# single.php has <a href="#"> after every div

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I just created an archive page for a custom post type and updated my permalinks, and suddenly my single.php has `<a href="#">` scattered all over it before `the_content();` starts.
Here's what the chrome dev tools look like:

[image: chrome dev tools view]

I would like to get rid of these because it makes my `the_title();` a link. Is there any way to fix this? Thanks

Comment: If you undo the creation of the archive page, do the `<a>` tags go away?

Comment: I deleted both archive.php and archive-event.php from my folder, removed `'has_archive' => true, ` from my custom post type, updated permalinks again and it's still the same

Comment: It has also affected some divs on my home page. it just adds  /# to the current link. It basically enters the first div of every page and makes it a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *suspect* you have some bad HTML somewhere - maybe an un-closed "a" tag in an invalid location or something like that.  Then, your browser is interpreting that as best it can.

To narrow down, look at the "raw" source of the page (Right-click, then "View page source") and review the HTML there where it's unprocessed by the browser.

You can also use an HTML validator like https://validator.w3.org/ to help find the key problem - but that can be a bit noisy if you have a lot of minor issues.

Comment: had an un-closed <a> tag in my header.php, the page source tip helped. Thanks